# How to get a 'clean' object from an angularfirecollection

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an angular fire collection that I am trying to use in an angular select with ng-options.

Feeding the angularfirecollection object creates an option for each element in the collection, plus an object for each method in the collection as well. (add, getByName, order, remove, update).

How can I get a 'clean' object from this angularfirecollection that doesnt contain these extra methods?

Comment: Please attach your code.    Did you check this:  http://angularfire.com/documentation.html#explicit

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: 
`<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="name as item.name for item in items | orderByPriority"></select>`. [More about `orderByPriority`](http://angularfire.com/flatdoc.html#orderbypriority) at AngularFire docs.